# Directus CMS multiple images field

Tags: content-management-system, directus

How do you input a field in Directus that allows you to select multiple images for upload? I can see only the file field, which allows for only one file upload. I need to create a gallery for a client with a variable number of pictures on each post.

Answer (score 4):

Developer of Directus here.

Currently Directus 7 only has the `file` interface, which supports only 1 file at a time. You can either setup a regular many-to-many interface to the Directus Files collection.

There's an open issue for it on GitHub here: https://github.com/directus/app/issues/956

I'll try to see if we can prioritize implementing a multiple-files interface, as it's an often needed way of adding files.

Comment: is this implemented in the current version ? @Rijk ?